# Strange Output Buffering Behavior in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, buffer

I am trying out a C shell implementation from an open course, yet there is something intriguing about the behavior of the output buffering.

The code goes like this (note the line where I use **pid = waitpid(-1, &r, WNOHANG)**):

```
int
main(void)
{
  static char buf[100];
  int fd, r;
  pid_t pid = 0;

  // Read and run input commands.
  while(getcmd(buf, sizeof(buf)) >= 0){
    if(buf[0] == 'c' && buf[1] == 'd' && buf[2] == ' '){
      buf[strlen(buf)-1] = 0;  // chop \n
      if(chdir(buf+3) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot cd %s\n", buf+3);
      continue;
    }
    if((pid = fork1()) == 0)
      runcmd(parsecmd(buf));
    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &r, WNOHANG)) >= 0) {
      if (errno == ECHILD) {
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

The runcmd function is like this (note that in **pipe handling** I create 2 child processes and wait for them to terminate):

```
void
runcmd(struct cmd *cmd)
{
  int p[2], r;
  struct execcmd *ecmd;
  struct pipecmd *pcmd;
  struct redircmd *rcmd;

  if(cmd == 0)
    exit(0);

  switch(cmd->type){
  case ' ':
    ecmd = (struct execcmd*)cmd;
    if(ecmd->argv[0] == 0) {
      exit(0);
    }
    // Your code here ...
    // fprintf(stderr, "starting to run cmd: %s\n", ecmd->argv[0]);
    execvp(ecmd->argv[0], ecmd->argv);
    fprintf(stderr, "exec error !\n");
    exit(-1);

    break;

  case '>':
  case '<':
    rcmd = (struct redircmd*)cmd;
    // fprintf(stderr, "starting to run <> cmd: %s\n", rcmd->file);
    // Your code here ...
    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
    if (rcmd->type == '<') {
      // input
      close(0);
      if (open(rcmd->file, O_RDONLY, mode) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opening file error !\n");
        exit(-1);
      }
    } else {
      // output
      close(1);
      if (open(rcmd->file, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, mode) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opening file error !\n");
        exit(-1);
      }
    }

    runcmd(rcmd->cmd);
    break;

  case '|':
    pcmd = (struct pipecmd*)cmd;
    // fprintf(stderr, "starting to run pcmd\n");
    // Your code here ...
    pipe(p);

    if (fork1() == 0) {
      // child for read, right side command
      close(0);
      if (dup(p[0]) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error when dup !\n");
        exit(-1);
      }
      close(p[0]);
      close(p[1]);
      runcmd(pcmd->right);
      fprintf(stderr, "exec error !\n");
    } 
    if (fork1() == 0) {
      // left side command for writing
      close(1);
      if (dup(p[1]) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dup error !\n");
        exit(-1);
      }
      close(p[0]);
      close(p[1]);
      runcmd(pcmd->left);
      fprintf(stderr, "exec error !\n");
    }
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
    int stat;
    wait(&stat);
    wait(&stat);

    break;

  default:
    fprintf(stderr, "unknown runcmd\n");
    exit(-1);
  }    
  exit(0);
}
```

The wierd thing is, when I execute "ls | sort" in the terminal, I constantly get the following output

```
6.828$ ls | sort
6.828$ a.out
sh.c
t.sh
```

This indicates that before the next command prompt "6828$" is printed, the output from the child process is still not flushed to terminal.

However, if I don't use **pid = waitpid(-1, &r, WNOHANG))** and use **pid = waitpid(-1, &r, 0))** (or **wait()**), the output would be normal like:

```
6.828$ ls | sort
a.out
sh.c
t.sh
```

I have been thinking about the cause of the problem for a long time but did not come up with a possible reason. Can anyone suggest some possible reason?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This code does not have well-defined behaviour:

```
while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &r, WNOHANG)) >= 0) {
  if (errno == ECHILD) {
      break;
  }
}
```

The `while` loop breaks immediately if `waitpid` returns -1, which is precisely what it returns in the case of an error. So if the body of the loop is entered, `waitpid` returned some non-negative value: either 0 -- indicating that the child is still executing -- or the pid of a child which had exited. Those are not error conditions, so the value of `errno` is not meaningful. It might be `ECHILD`, in which case the loop will incorrectly break.

You **must** only check the value of `errno` in cases where the value is meaningful. Or, to be more precise, quoting the [Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html):

> The value of `errno` shall be defined only after a call to a function for which it is explicitly stated to be set and until it is changed by the next function call or if the application assigns it a value. The value of `errno` should only be examined when it is indicated to be valid by a function's return value.

But I'm puzzled why you feel it necessary to busy loop using `WNOHANG`. That's a massive waste of resources, since your parent process will repeatedly execute the system call until the child actually terminates. Since you really intend to wait until the child terminates, it would make much more sense to just call `wait` or to specify `0` as a flag value to `waitpid`.

On the other hand, you might want to repeat the `wait` (or `waitpid`) if it  returns -1 with `errno` set to `EINTR`. And if it returns `-1` and `errno` is neither `EINTR` nor `ECHILD`, then some hard error has occurred which you might want to log. But that's not related to your problem, afaics.